# Bulk insert operations process records without errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

From what I understand, the best way to bulk insert data using C# and SQL Server is to use a table type and pass in a data table. 
Our current process flow is to process / insert data one record at a time (even if there are thousands of records) so that we are able to successfully process valid records and report back on errors. Obviously this is a huge performance issue.

Is there any way to do bulk insert operations that will allow valid records to be inserted and invalid records to fail?
If so, how do you find out which records passed and which ones failed or caused an error?

Comment: This [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc) discuss this in detail.

Comment: This is a really interesting article, and it will give me some additional ideas on where to go with this, but it was written in 2012. I am wondering if anything has changed since then with new versions of SQL Server or the .Net Framework. Is bulk copy still the best way to go vs using a table type?

Answer (score 0):

I think only SSIS can do what you describe. What I have done in the past is to use SQLXML to bulk load data to SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171993.aspx).

Basically what I did is this:

1. create an XML Schema that corresponds to the table structure and added mapping attributes (see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171721.aspx)
2. create the XML file from C# using the XML Schema for serialisation of my data
3. since XML Bulk loading fails in the first error like BulkInsert, I had to parse the XML document using XMLReader (serially to support big XML files) and validate it against the schema. This way I knew which elements were not conforming to the schema and I could remove them and store them in another XML file.
4. bulk load the fixed XML file to the SQL Server table

So the main I/O here includes: having a reader stream to read the XML and 2 writer streams to write the valid and invalid XML files and finally bulk loading the valid XML file.

The performance is great btw (I am able to bulk load 1GB file in less than 5 mins on my laptop but this can vary depending on the disk speed and CPU). The memory utilisation is very low btw.